# Server.MapPath gives wrong path, exception "The given path's format is not supported" when running on IIS server?

Tags: c#, exception, path, server.mappath

Currently, I'm using the codes below to save a file to a directory on my website.

```
//save the file to the server
String savePath = Server.MapPath("..\\temp\\") + file;
FileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs(savePath);
```

When I'm running the application on my computer, it returns the path:

"E:\dotnet\Project\Implementation\Source Code\Project\Project.UI\temp\Sample.csv"

However, when running on a real server, it throws exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
```

The expected path that I would like to have is "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project\temp".

Am I doing things correctly or not? If not then can someone explain to me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server.MapPath maps a virtual path to a physical one on the server. If you replace your backslashes with forward-slashes you should be ok:

```
Server.MapPath("../temp/")
```

You can also use the root relative path:

```
Server.MapPath("~/temp/");
```

Comment: I tried your solutions that it returns the same path that I received before when running the web on local. But still have exception "The given path's format is not supported" when running on IIS. Pls help :(

Comment: never mind, I figured out the problem: write access denied in that directory!